# Docker: you must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize my backend API (Ruby on Rails and Postgres), I'm stuck in the postgres setting up, as a first step I would like to show you the docker log:

[image: postgres_error]

Basically, I think the most important settings related to Postgres are in my .env file, please take a look:

```
RORLETSORDER_ADMIN_USER=hftamayo
RORLETSORDER_ADMIN_PASSWORD=XXX
RORLETSORDER_DATABASE_NAME=rorletsorder_production
RORLETSORDER_DATABASE_USERNAME=rorletsorder
RORLETSORDER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=XXX
RORLETSORDER_DATABASE_HOST= rorletsorderdatabase
```

So, my question is: what am I missing to set up properly the postgres admin user and password?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` environment variable *in the environment of the postgres container*. That means either (a) in your `.env` file, or (b) in the `environment` section of the service. You're doing neither right now.

See [the documentation for that image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for more information.